# How to sum values in an array with different hash

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I want to sum the total values of the same items in an array.

I have an array as

```
[{"a"=>1},{"b"=>2},{"c"=>3},{"a"=>2},{"b"=>4}]
```

I want to get the result as

```
[{"a"=>3},{"b"=>6},{"c"=>3}]
```

Which method can do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if:

```
array = [{"a"=>1},{"b"=>2},{"c"=>3},{"a"=>2},{"b"=>4}]
```

then you can do:

```
array.inject(Hash.new{|h,k| h[k] = 0})
      { |h, a| k, v = a.flatten;  h[k] += v; h }.
      map{|arr| Hash[*arr] }
#=> [{"a"=>3}, {"b"=>6}, {"c"=>3}]
```

or:

```
array.each_with_object(Hash.new{|h,k| h[k] = 0})
      { |a, h| k, v = a.flatten;  h[k] += v }.
      map{|arr| Hash[*arr] }
#=> [{"a"=>3}, {"b"=>6}, {"c"=>3}]
```

Comment: `#each_with_object` is what I am looking for if any one used or not. :-) But you did, so you saved my time..:P +1

Comment: 1. You don't need `to_a`. (Why?). 2. You don't need `; h` with `each_with_object` (which is why @Arup suggested the latter). 3. Is `"arr"` a suitable name? The formating is much improved.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Yes exactly.. That's why I don't use `#inject` much if I am not forced to.. :P

Answer (score 2):

It can be done as follows

```
array.group_by { |h| h.keys.first }.
values.
map {|x| x.reduce({}) { |h1, h2| h1.merge(h2) { |_, o, n| o + n } }

#=> [{"a"=>3}, {"b"=>6}, {"c"=>3}]
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this. It is instructive to see a few, even some that may be unusual and/or not especially efficient.

Here is another way:

```
arr = [{"a"=>1},{"b"=>2},{"c"=>3},{"a"=>2},{"b"=>4}]

arr.flat_map(&:keys)
   .uniq
   .map { |k| { k=>arr.reduce(0) { |t,g| t + (g.key?(k) ? g[k] : 0) } } } 
  #=> [{"a"=>3}, {"b"=>6}, {"c"=>3}]
```

Since `nil.to_i => 0`, we could instead write `reduce`'s block as:

```
   { |t,g| t+g[k].to_i }
```

Answer (score 1):

Every time you want to transform a collection in not a one-to-one way, it's job for `#reduce`. For one-to-one transformations we use `#map`.

```
array.reduce({}) { |h, acc| acc.merge(h) {|_k, o, n| o+n } }.zip.map(&:to_h)
# => [{"b"=>6}, {"a"=>3}, {"c"=>3}]
```

Here we use reduce with the initial value `{}`, which is passed to the block as the `acc` parameter, and then we use `#merge` with manual "conflicts resolution". It means that the block is called only when the key we're trying to merge is already present in the method receiver, `acc`. After that we break the hash into an array of hashes.

Comment: You need to add `.map { |k,v| {k=>v}}` or something similar to the end to get the result into the form specified (array of hashes).

Comment: it should produce: `[{"a"=>3},{"b"=>6},{"c"=>3}]` not `{"b"=>6, "a"=>3, "c"=>3}`. I think you need to do something like @CarySwoveland mentioned.